# Gradle: get task command line arguments inside the task

Tags: gradle, groovy, automated-tests

I'm running my tests with gradle using the command line:

```
./gradlew testManager:uiTest -PignoreTestFailures=true" +
     "-DCHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=${env.CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION}" +
     "-DBASE_URL=${params.BASE_URL}"
```

I need to propagate passed properties (e.g. `BASE_URL`) to the JMV with tests from the gradle task.
I know I could do the following inside the task:
`systemProperties System.properties`

But I'd like to avoid passing the whole set, as it overrides some other required values in tests.

So the question is: is there a way to get the only properties passed via `-D` command line parameter,  inside the gradle task?

Answer (score 0):

Found this pretty easy way:

```
task uiTest(type: Test) {
    doFirst {
        /* Propagate only command line start properties (-D) to the tests */
        project.gradle.startParameter.systemPropertiesArgs.entrySet().collect() {
            systemProperty it.key, it.value
        }
    }
}
```

So in a case of

```
./gradlew testManager:uiTest -PincludeTests=saveReleaseState/** -DBASE_URL=foobar
```

The tests receive only `BASE_URL=foobar`